# Can I have one-to-one relation between observer and subject?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I'm trying to create a model with observer design pattern. I'm wondering that my subject can have only one observer. I usually see one subject and many observers in examples.

Comment: The subject can have zero, one or many observers, it shouldn't care.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to create a model according your answer